# Why is the limit of ${\tan(x)}^{\cos( x)}$ as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ equals 1?

Tags: calculus

Why is the limit of ${\tan(x)}^{\cos( x)}$ as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ equals 1? Please explain and include step by step solution.

I've changed it into the lny = cos ln tan x. That is equal to infinity X 0. What would be the next step.

Comment: What have you tried? Fair warning: You shouldn't expect step-by-step solutions on Math.SE when you (a) are asking us to do what looks like a homework problem and (b) haven't shown what you've attempted/what's confusing you.

Comment: $\pi/2=1$? Wow!

Comment: Please read the FAQ and edit this question, or your question will rapidly be downvoted and put on hold.  Read Dan's advice.

Comment: I've changed it into the lny = cos ln tan x. That is equal to infinity X 0. What would be the next step?

Comment: @StefanSmith I think the tone of the question is actually polite, but I agree that more evidence of effort would be nice.

Comment: @ Stefan Smith. I have tried other sites and am coming to math.stackexchange as a last resort. Math.StackExchange is a math community and people here should be interested in helping others understand the math better.

Comment: @user44816 You should nevertheless make an effort to solve the problem yourself and show what you have done.

Comment: @triple_sec : maybe "impolite" wasn't the best word, but asking for a step by step solution without providing any evidence of one's own efforts does not seem like good manners.  Isn't there a FAQ for first-time posters?

Comment: @user44816 : You changed your equation to something like " $\ln y = \cos \ln \tan x$".  That is a big improvement, but you need to include it in the _question_, not just in a comment.  You can edit your question by clicking "edit" under the question.  By the way, I did not downvote your question.

Comment: I posted my work in a comment. I've changed it into the lny = cos ln tan x. That is equal to infinity X 0. What would be the next step? Would you be so kind as to offer your help now that you've seen some of my effort?

Comment: @user44816 : redundant advice : post your work in the _question_, not just in a comment.

Comment: @user44816 : one more thing : even if you get a good answer, you should _still_ improve your question, so it is apparent to everyone (even if they don't dig through the comments) that you have put some effort into the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, $$\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}=\exp[\cos(x)\log(\tan(x))].$$ As $x\nearrow\pi/2$, $\tan(x)\to+\infty$, so that $\log(\tan(x))\to\infty$. On the other hand, $\cos(x)$ converges to $0$, so that this limit is of the form “$0\cdot\infty$”.

Let's try converting it to a fraction and use L'Hôpital's rule:
\begin{align*}
&\,\lim_{x\nearrow\pi/2}\cos(x)\log(\tan(x))=\lim_{x\nearrow\pi/2}\frac{\log(\tan(x))}{\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}}=\lim_{x\nearrow\pi/2}\frac{\dfrac{1}{\tan(x)}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}{-\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\cdot(-\sin(x))}\\
=&\,\lim_{x\nearrow\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=0.
\end{align*}

Now,
\begin{align*}
&\,\lim_{x\nearrow\pi/2}\tan(x)^{\cos(x)}=\lim_{x\nearrow\pi/2}\exp[\cos(x)\log(\tan(x))]=\exp\left[\lim_{x\nearrow\pi/2}\cos(x)\log(\tan(x))\right]\\
=&\,\exp(0)=1.\end{align*}

Note that this is the limit from the left. The right-hand side limit does not exist, because $\tan(x)<0$ for $x\in(\pi/2,\pi/2+\varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, and, in general, you can't raise a negative number to an arbitrary power (only in special cases). In fact, for such values, the function is not even *defined*.

Comment: you should explain to the OP that you are taking the limit as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ from the left, since that is not literally what the OP asked for.

Comment: @StefanSmith You're right, I added an explanation.

Comment: How did you get 1 / cos^2x in the denominator?

Comment: $(1/x)'=-(1/x^2)$, so $(1/\cos(x))'=-1/(\cos^2(x))\cdot(\cos(x))'$ by the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ approaching $\pi/2$ from *below*:
Instead of using L'Hospital, one can also write
$$\cos(x)\log(\tan x ) = \cos(x)\log(\frac{\sin x }{\cos x}) = \cos(x)\log(\sin x) - \cos(x)\log(\cos x) $$
where each of the two terms on the right tends to $0$ separately -- the first one simply by continuity, the second one by the substitution $u=\cos x$, which makes the limit into $\lim_{u\to 0^{+}}u \log u$ which is well known to be $0$.